# Can I route a drain pipe under a gas line?

Tags: plumbing, drainage, building-regulations, underground

I want to reroute an outdoor drain pipe (rain water) to a better location but there is a gas line that is in the path that the drain pipe needs to go. Can I route the pipe below the gas line? I'm open to any suggestions on how to get the pipe routed properly.

Here is my poor illustration and photo to help understand the issue. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's standard ABS drain pipe, I don't see any reason why this couldn't be done. Your gas line is metal. As long as the plastic stays below it it should be fine. I would contact the gas company and just double check that they're kosher with it. Be sure to call the local utility dig locator and have them mark things too, or you'll be liable for damages.